# How to solve performance problems with postgres and null Values?

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, partial

After remodeling a table I have some performance problems.

Former DB-Layout was table *masterOld* with 2 tables inherits from *masterOld*: *part1Old* and *part2Old*. In *masterOld* were 7 million rows (*part1Old*: 5 millions, *part2Old*: 2 millions).

Now we have only one new table *masterNew* with 7 million rows.

DDL:
export:

```
CREATE TABLE public.export (
  id_firma BIGINT,
  status VARCHAR(32)
) 
WITH (oids = false);

CREATE INDEX export_idx ON public.export
  USING btree (id_firma);
```

masterNew:

```
CREATE TABLE public."masterNew" (
id_firma BIGINT,
id_bestand BIGINT NOT NULL,
status VARCHAR(32),
sperre VARCHAR(32),
CONSTRAINT "masterNew_2016_pkey" PRIMARY KEY(id_bestand)
) 
WITH (oids = false);

CREATE INDEX "masterNew_2016_pi_idx" ON public."masterNew"
USING btree (id_firma)
WHERE ((status IS NULL) AND (sperre IS NULL));

CREATE INDEX "masterNew_sperre_2016" ON public."masterNew"
USING btree (sperre COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX "masterNew_status_2016" ON public."masterNew"
USING btree (status COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

masterOld:

```
CREATE TABLE public."masterOld" (
  id_firma BIGINT,
  id_bestand BIGINT NOT NULL,
  status VARCHAR(32),
  sperre VARCHAR(32),
  CONSTRAINT "masterOld_pkey" PRIMARY KEY(id_bestand)
) 
WITH (oids = false);

CREATE INDEX "masterOld_idx" ON public."masterOld"
  USING btree (id_firma);

CREATE INDEX "masterOld_sperre" ON public."masterOld"
  USING btree (sperre COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX "masterOld_status" ON public."masterOld"
  USING btree (status COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

part1Old:

```
CREATE TABLE public."part1Old" (
  CONSTRAINT "part1Old_idx" PRIMARY KEY(id_bestand)
) INHERITS (public."masterOld")

WITH (oids = false);

CREATE INDEX "part1Old_idx1" ON public."part1Old"
  USING btree (id_firma);

CREATE INDEX "part1Old_idx2" ON public."part1Old"
  USING btree (status COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX "part1Old_idx3" ON public."part1Old"
  USING btree (sperre COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

part2Old:

```
CREATE TABLE public."part2Old" (
  CONSTRAINT "part2Old_idx" PRIMARY KEY(id_bestand)
) INHERITS (public."masterOld")

WITH (oids = false);

CREATE INDEX "part2Old_idx1" ON public."part2Old"
  USING btree (id_firma);

CREATE INDEX "part2Old_idx2" ON public."part2Old"
  USING btree (status COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX "part2Old_idx3" ON public."part2Old"
  USING btree (sperre COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

In the *export* table are 1.2 million rows.

Old:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT b.id, b.status
FROM export b, masterOld mb
WHERE mb.sperre IS NULL
  AND mb.status IS NULL
  AND b.id_firma = mb.id_firma
LIMIT 100;
```

[Plan on explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/SCBo)

```
- Plan: 
Node Type: "Limit"
Startup Cost: 0.00
Total Cost: 0.09
Plan Rows: 100
Plan Width: 90
Plans: 
  - Node Type: "Nested Loop"
    Parent Relationship: "Outer"
    Join Type: "Inner"
    Startup Cost: 0.00
    Total Cost: 118535034.59
    Plan Rows: 126126068850
    Plan Width: 90
    Plans: 
      - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
        Parent Relationship: "Outer"
        Relation Name: "export"
        Alias: "b"
        Startup Cost: 0.00
        Total Cost: 79129.80
        Plan Rows: 5485680
        Plan Width: 90
      - Node Type: "Append"
        Parent Relationship: "Inner"
        Startup Cost: 0.00
        Total Cost: 21.56
        Plan Rows: 3
        Plan Width: 8
        Plans: 
          - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
            Parent Relationship: "Member"
            Relation Name: "masterOld"
            Alias: "mb"
            Startup Cost: 0.00
            Total Cost: 1.10
            Plan Rows: 1
            Plan Width: 8
            Filter: "((sperre IS NULL) AND (status IS NULL) AND (b.id = id))"
          - Node Type: "Index Scan"
            Parent Relationship: "Member"
            Scan Direction: "Forward"
            Index Name: "part1Old_idx9"
            Relation Name: "part1Old"
            Alias: "mb_1"
            Startup Cost: 0.43
            Total Cost: 12.20
            Plan Rows: 1
            Plan Width: 8
            Index Cond: "(id = b.id)"
            Filter: "((sperre IS NULL) AND (status IS NULL))"
          - Node Type: "Index Scan"
            Parent Relationship: "Member"
            Scan Direction: "Forward"
            Index Name: "part2Old_idx"
            Relation Name: "part2Old"
            Alias: "mb_2"
            Startup Cost: 0.43
            Total Cost: 8.26
            Plan Rows: 1
            Plan Width: 8
            Index Cond: "(id = b.id)"
            Filter: "((sperre IS NULL) AND (status IS NULL))"
```

There were no speed problems.

New:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT b.id, b.status
FROM export b, masterNew mb
WHERE mb.sperre IS NULL
  AND mb.status IS NULL
  AND b.id = mb.id
LIMIT 100;
```

[Plan on explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/eAqG)

```
- Plan: 
Node Type: "Limit"
Startup Cost: 5.38
Total Cost: 306.99
Plan Rows: 100
Plan Width: 90
Plans: 
  - Node Type: "Nested Loop"
    Parent Relationship: "Outer"
    Join Type: "Inner"
    Startup Cost: 5.38
    Total Cost: 14973468.06
    Plan Rows: 4964540
    Plan Width: 90
    Join Filter: "(b.id = mb.id)"
    Plans: 
      - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
        Parent Relationship: "Outer"
        Relation Name: "export"
        Alias: "b"
        Startup Cost: 0.00
        Total Cost: 79129.80
        Plan Rows: 5485680
        Plan Width: 90
      - Node Type: "Materialize"
        Parent Relationship: "Inner"
        Startup Cost: 5.38
        Total Cost: 717.51
        Plan Rows: 181
        Plan Width: 8
        Plans: 
          - Node Type: "Bitmap Heap Scan"
            Parent Relationship: "Outer"
            Relation Name: "masterNew"
            Alias: "mb"
            Startup Cost: 5.38
            Total Cost: 716.61
            Plan Rows: 181
            Plan Width: 8
            Recheck Cond: "((status IS NULL) AND (sperre IS NULL))"
            Plans: 
              - Node Type: "Bitmap Index Scan"
                Parent Relationship: "Outer"
                Index Name: "masterNew_2016_pi_idx"
                Startup Cost: 0.00
                Total Cost: 5.34
                Plan Rows: 181
                Plan Width: 0
```

There we have our problem.
We have tried to fix it using a partial Index on *id* with `status is null and sperre is null` .
If we don't use `sperre is null` in this query it is quick. I think we have these problems because *sperre* and *status* have much null values. *status*: 67% null and *sperre*: 97% null .
On each table there are btree indexes on *id*, *sperre* and *status*.
On *masterNew* there is a partial Index on *id* with `sperre is null and status is null`.

Can somebody help me with these performance Problem.
What can I try to solve this.

Comment: Can you post the query plans to http://explain.depesz.com?

Comment: Can you add the DDL (including constraints and indexes) to the query?

Comment: Posted both DDL and plans